# Laravel auth() component not available on error views

Tags: php, laravel

- Framework: Laravel 9.x

I'm attempting to use custom error pages. These are located in the default location: `/resources/views/errors/...`.

These load as expected. However, they extend the base view template. This template uses the `auth()->user()` functionality to make decisions on visible menus.

The `auth()->user()` does not work on the error views. Note that it works as expected on other views.

How do I load the authenticated user for these error file views?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the end of your route file for 404 error. Usually 404 doesn't get the session.

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return abort(404);
});
```

All other errors such as 401, 403, 419, 429, 500, 503 these gets the session by default you do not need to do anything for that. Basically 404 means you do not have that route so system kicks user out of the system, in that case kernel does not load with all providers. if provider do not load you will not get session. So for 404 we are telling our system let our user stay but if the page is not available use fallback route.

If you want to test it for each errors you can do something like this.

- Create a blank route

```
Route::get('/blank', fn() => abort(401));
```

- go to `401.blade.php` change message to `auth()->user()->id`.
- visit the `/blank` URL.

If you see your id your session is working.

Comment: How do I do this for 401, 403 etc?

Comment: 401, 403, 419, 429, 500, 503 all these errors gets the session by default you do not need to do anything for that. Basically 404 means you do not have that route so system kicks user out of the system, in that case kernel does not load with all providers. if provider do not load you will not get session. So for 404 we are telling our system let our user stay but if the page is not available use fallback route. SIMPLE. I hope this will clear your confusion. Choose as best answer if this really helps you. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to test it for each errors you can do something like this ---> Create a blank route `Route::get('/blank', fn() => abort(401));` .... now go to `401.blade.php` change message to `auth()->user()->id` ... now visit the `/blank` url. if you see your id your session is working.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Marked as answer!